# split hash into hashes Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, key

I'm new to Ruby

I have a Hash with a big collection of key => value pairs. I would like to split this Hash into hashes depending on the key.

```
{..."LoopLabs "=>1, "Influanza "=>1, "Cleo Media "=>1, "Adento "=>1, "HireRadar "=>1, "FidorFactory "=>1, "Four Energy "=>1, "Liefery "=>5, "Weaveworks "=>1, "Gastrofix "=>1 }
```

I expect the following result:

```
{ label: "LoopLabs", values: [[1]] }
{ label: "Influanza", values: [[1]] }
{ label: "Liefery", values: [[5]] }
...
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
hash = {"LoopLabs "=>1, "Influanza "=>1, "Cleo Media "=>1, "Adento "=>1, "HireRadar "=>1, "FidorFactory "=>1, "Four Energy "=>1, "Liefery "=>5, "Weaveworks "=>1, "Gastrofix "=>1 }
hash.map {|k,v| {label: k, values: [[v]]}}
# => [{:label=>"LoopLabs ", :values=>[[1]]},
# {:label=>"Influanza ", :values=>[[1]]},
# {:label=>"Cleo Media ", :values=>[[1]]},
# {:label=>"Adento ", :values=>[[1]]},
# {:label=>"HireRadar ", :values=>[[1]]},
# {:label=>"FidorFactory ", :values=>[[1]]},
# {:label=>"Four Energy ", :values=>[[1]]},
# {:label=>"Liefery ", :values=>[[5]]},
# {:label=>"Weaveworks ", :values=>[[1]]},
# {:label=>"Gastrofix ", :values=>[[1]]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic way to accomplish this would be:

```
hash.dup
    .group_by(&:shift)
    .map(&%i|label values|.method(:zip))
    .map(&:to_h)
```